# Limit drag and drop to within a single control

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, instance

I've looked and looked and can't find an answer.

I have a `TreeView`. It has Drag and Drop to allow moving of Nodes within the tree.

I want to limit the drag and drop to only work within that one control, within a single instance of the application (the application itself can run more than one instance).

I've tried the following:

```
private void SubFolderTreeView_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    TreeView source = sender as TreeView;    // also tried = (TreeView) sender;

    if (source == this.SubFolderTreeView && e.Data.GetDataPresent("System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode", false))
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move; // Okay, set the visual effect
    else
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None; // Unknown data, ignore it
}
```

Unfortunately, a second instance of the same application will still be able to drag from its `TreeView` to the first TreeView: `(source == this.SubFolderTreeView)` is true

I have not tested if a totally different treeview could drag to mine, though I doubt it, but the above behaviour is already a fail.

I tried some other things - comparing the form or the control's handle also didn't work

```
bool isSameForm = ((MyForm) source.TopLevelControl == this);    // still true
bool isSameHandle = (((Control)source).Handle == ((Control)this.SubFolderTreeView).Handle);     // still true
```

The only other things I can think of, off the top of my head, is a random number stored in the TreeView or Form (probably won't work), and checking the absolute screen position of the control (not the best method).

I could of course stick a mutex in the application and so only allow one instance to run, but I'd rather not.

Can anyone suggest a good way of doing this?

Comment: I would suggest using a Mutex.. why are you so hesitant to use Mutex..?

Comment: You cannot get the drag source, part of the D+D contract.  A very simple fix is to use a private field in your form class.  Assign it before calling DoDragDrop, set it back to null afterwards.  It will be null when the TreeNode came from another process.

Comment: DJ Kraze, maybe I've misunderstood Mutex use, but I always thought they were used to prevent more than one instance of an application running at the same time, which I don't want (I want 1 OR MORE running). Is there a way that you could use it specific to this case? (Asked more for learning sake, as Hans has already provided a working solution)

Comment: @JamesCarlyle-Clarke - a mutex is used to prevent simultaneous access to a shared resource, where "shared resource" has a really, really broad definition. "Permission to start" would be an example (i.e., only one instance of a program running), but "permission to accept a drag/drop" would be another example. Your program would attempt to acquire the mutex, and if successful, set a flag that the drop handler could see. When the drop is completed, the program would release the mutex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To flesh out Hans Passant's solution (which worked perfectly, thanks Hans) for future reference and other searchers into this problem, I used the code:

```
// prevents dragging from other instances of this form - thanks to Hans Passant
private bool DragDropFromThisForm = false;

private void SubFolderTreeView_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
{
    // Initiate drag/drop
    DragDropFromThisForm = true;
    DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.Move);
    DragDropFromThisForm = false;
}

private void SubFolderTreeView_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    MyForm form = (MyForm) (sender as TreeView).TopLevelControl;

    if (form.DragDropFromThisForm && e.Data.GetDataPresent("System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode", false))
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move; // Okay, set the visual effect
    else
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None; // Unknown data, ignore it
}
```

It may well be that DJ Kraze's answer would also work, and perhaps be a tad more elegant, but Hans' solution is lightweight and effective.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really following the restrictions, seems like flawed logic with the information you've given (all identical instances, but only one can have drag and drop - what??), but some suggestions:

- Have a property that determines whether nodes can 'drag and drop' and only set it in the one instance.
- Only subscribe to the event on the one instance that you want to be able to 'drag and drop' on.
- Create a separate TreeView class that supports dragging and dropping, and instantiate the base TreeView everywhere else.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it well. The form has a TreeView. I want the nodes within the TreeView to be draggable within that TreeView, but no further (not to other forms, not to other instances of my form).

So TreeView A in Form A can drag nodes within TreeView A only. TreeView B in Form B can drag nodes within TreeView B only. TreeView A cannot drag a node to TreeView B, or vice versa.